# Pair blocking for probabilistic linkage with time periods that cross over midnight

Tags: r, lubridate

I'm trying to link 2 health care data sets based on an event times using the `recline2` package in R.  Because the times are not exactly recorded in the two data sets I have to work with a time interval, but this is causing problems with  `recline2::pair_blocking()`  as it will not create pairs based on a %within% relationship. Also, because the data sometimes crosses midnight, I can't just use dates.

Unfortunately, matching via other data (gender, age, etc) is not possible due to poor data quality.

The actual data sets each have over 30 000 cases in them, some of which don't have a pair, so the solution needs to be efficient on CPU usage.

below is a sample problem set where Case 1 in X should pair with Case 1 in Y, Case 2 in X should pair with Case 2 in Y,....

```
library(lubridate)
#Dataset X
case.x<- c(1,2,3,4) 
Event_time<- c("1/2/23 14:56:00", "4/5/23 23:56:00", "7/6/23 00:42:00", "2/5/23 05:06:00")
Location<- c( "A", "B", "A", "B")
X<- data.frame(case.x,Event_time, Location)
X$Event_time<-dmy_hms(Event_time)

#Dataset Y
case.y<- c(1,2,3,4) 
event_range_start<- c("1/2/23 13:56:00", "4/5/23 22:56:00", "6/6/23 23:42:00", "2/5/23 04:06:00")
event_range_end<- c("1/2/23 15:56:00", "5/5/23 00:56:00", "7/6/23 01:42:00", "2/5/23 06:06:00")
Location<- Location<- c( "A", "B", "A", "B")
Y<- data.frame(case.y,event_range_start,event_range_end, Location)
Y$event_range<- interval(dmy_hms(Y$event_range_start), dmy_hms(Y$event_range_end))
```

I  am looking for a solution to the issues of blocking pair based of a time range, preferably using reclin2, but other probabilistic linkage packages could be considered if necessary .

Comment: If both were a real R “Date” I would have imagined that interval should be easy to calculate.

Comment: @IRTFM  thanks for the reply, I'm not trying to calculate the interval.  I'm trying to setup pairs for probabilistic matching. the problem I am having is that the stock pair building function works on direct matches. It doesn't support blocking based on occurrence of a time with in an interval.  
I was hoping someone would know of another function or have a work around.

Comment: Just to clarify, the only columns available to use as a basis for the join are X$Event_time, Y$event_range_start, and Y$event_range_end?

Comment: @LTyrone:  no. there are other columns available, including DOB, Gender, postal code, and provincial health number. However due to the poor quality of data entry many of these have errors. The size of the data set means i need to narrow the blocking down to 1hr +/- to make it more reliable.    date time stamps are more reliable, but not exact matches.  the two data sets come from different systems, so the date/time are close but not perfect. 
I have confirmed that event date/time +/- 1 hours is reliable using other means.  I just don't know how to build the blocking.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that uses the `fuzzyjoin` package. Note that I have modified the last event_range_end value in Y to demonstrate how unmatched values will be treated. This example defines a match as an Event_time that is >= event_range_start and < event_range_end (as in `match_fun`). Alter these parameters to your needs if this is incorrect.

If there are cases where > 1 Event_time falls within a given range, you will then need to use your other variables such as DOB to determine which record is correct. If you do need a secondary matching phase using other variables, comment below explaining the issue and I'll update this answer.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(fuzzyjoin)

# Modified dataset Y
case.y<- c(1,2,3,4) 
event_range_start <- c("1/2/23 13:56:00",
                       "4/5/23 22:56:00",
                       "6/6/23 23:42:00",
                       "2/5/23 04:06:00")
event_range_end <- c("1/2/23 15:56:00",
                     "5/5/23 00:56:00",
                     "7/6/23 01:42:00",
                     "2/5/23 05:05:00") 
Location <- Location<- c( "A", "B", "A", "B")

Y <- data.frame(case.y, event_range_start, event_range_end, Location)
Y$event_range_start <- dmy_hms(Y$event_range_start)
Y$event_range_end <- dmy_hms(Y$event_range_end)

# Join X and Y and filter based on event range columns
df <- X %>%
  fuzzy_left_join(Y,
                  by = c("Event_time" = "event_range_start",
                         "Event_time" = "event_range_end"),
                  match_fun = list(`>=`, `<`))


df
case.x            Event_time Location.x case.y   event_range_start     event_range_end Location.y 
1      1 2023-02-01 14:56:00          A      1 2023-02-01 13:56:00 2023-02-01 15:56:00          A
2      2 2023-05-04 23:56:00          B      2 2023-05-04 22:56:00 2023-05-05 00:56:00          B
3      3 2023-06-07 00:42:00          A      3 2023-06-06 23:42:00 2023-06-07 01:42:00          A
4      4 2023-05-02 05:06:00          B     NA                <NA>                <NA>       <NA>
```